# bash - awk padding a hex number with zeroes

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Input:

```
[0x000] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000000a00000  ,abcd             ,143     ,65535   }
[0x001] : {foo   ,blah   ,0x0000000001e00000  ,abcd             ,142     ,65535   }
[0x002] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000003000000  ,abcd             ,141     ,155     }
[0x003] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000003000000  ,abcd             ,144     ,156     }
```

Desired output:

```
0x0000 N/A 143
0x0002 155 141
0x0003 156 144
```

Currently using:
`sed -e 's/65535/N\/A/g' -e 's/[][},]//g' | awk '/foo/ {print $1,$NF,$(NF-1)}'`

I'd like to pad the first field to a 4 char hex number? How should I do it?

The input itself can already be a 4 char hex. In that case it should leave it as is.

Also, is there a way to merge the sed and the awk into a single command?

Thanks!

Comment: is your first field always 3 digit hex number?

Comment: No. It can be 4 already :) I want this to be a generic script.

Comment: so what if it has 4? Do you want to append another 0 or leave it?

Comment: Do you need to test if the line contains `65535`?

Comment: It can contain another value other than 65535 which shouldn't be modified but printed as is.

Comment: You REALLY should update your posted sample input and expected output to at least include lines that 1) don't contain `foo`, 2) have 4-digit hex numbers already, and 3) have some value other than 65535 in that field. Otherwise you're likely to get answers that only solve the parts of your problem covered by your sample input/output.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` line should do it alone:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ \t,:{}\\[\\]x]+"} $10==65535{$10="N/A"} {printf "0x%.4x %s %s\n", $3, $10, $9}'
```

Works with `mawk` and `gawk`.

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS=...}`: sets the field separator to `<space>`, `<tab>`, `,`, `[`, `]`, `:`, `{`, `}` and `x`.
- `$10==65535{$8="N/A"}` If the 10th variable equals to 65535 is is set to `N/A`
- `printf ...` print the needed values in the desired output

Comment: You could just get `printf` to zero-pad the output; that's what `printf` is for.

Comment: This also change line that should not be changed.  Only line with `65535` should be changed.

Comment: @Jotne What line does it also changes then? If the 10th field equals 65535 is is changed, only then.

Comment: Read OPs comment `It can contain another value other than 65535 which shouldn't be modified but printed as is`.  So if line contains `more data`, just print it.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your notice. I changed my answer

Comment: @Jotne yes it IS printed, if it is another value. I tested it right now. I don't get your point. The OP don't means the whole line, he means the value of that field.

Comment: `It can contain another value other than 65535 which shouldn't be modified but printed as is` For me that means do not change the line.  Se my example data and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mawk**, i have just modified your script, however u can get all this done with `awk` (`mawk` in this case) itself:

```
(sed -e 's/65535/N\/A/g' -e 's/[][},]//g' | mawk '/foo/ {printf ("0x%04x %s %s\n", $1,$NF,$(NF-1))}') < File
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F, '$6+0=="65535" {split($1,a,"[][]");$0=(length(a[2])==6?a[2]:"0x0"substr(a[2],3,4)) " N/A " $5}1' file
0x0000 N/A 143
0x2001 N/A 142
0x0002 N/A 141
```

If line contains `65535` change it, if not just print it.
Test if length of hex is `6` character, if yes, just use it.
If not, pad an extra `0` to it.

Example data:

```
cat file
[0x000] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000000a00000  ,abcd             ,143     ,65535   }
[0x2001] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000001e00000  ,abcd             ,142     ,65535   }
[0x002] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000003000000  ,abcd             ,141     ,65535   }
This line should not be modified
[0x002] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000003000000  ,abcd             ,141     ,65533   }
```

```
awk -F, '$6+0=="65535" {split($1,a,"[][]");$0=(length(a[2])==6?a[2]:"0x0"substr(a[2],3,4)) " N/A " $5}1' file
0x0000 N/A 143
0x2001 N/A 142
0x0002 N/A 141
This line should not be modified
[0x002] : {foo   ,bar    ,0x0000000003000000  ,abcd             ,141     ,65533   }
```

Comment: @Maxim_united To make sure I am testing against 65535 and not 65535 (so space behind is removed)

Comment: @JID Fixed so it test for the length of the hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed 's#\[0x\([[:xdigit:]]*\)].*,\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]*,[^,]*#0x0\1 N/A \2#;s/0x0\([[:xdigit:]]\{4\}\)/0x\1/' YourFile
```

- take 2 group, first the hexa at start and the last before last `,` (using sed pattern behavior) and reformat with content of the 2 group
- could be shorter using  instead of `[[:space:]]` if space char are used instead of tab, and use of `[0-9a-f]` instead of `[[:xdigit:]]`
- added the 4 hexa correction (thanks @jotne)

Posix version so `--posix` for GNU sed

Comment: OP said the field could already contain 4 digits, same problem as my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Ok with perl use this below command:

```
perl -lane '$F[6]=~s/,/N\/A /g;
            if($F[7]=~/65535/){printf "0x%04s $F[6]\n", $1 if(/^\[0x([^\]]*)\]/)}
            else{print}' your_file
```

Comment: This also change line that does not have  `65535`.  Se my post and OPs comment in his post.

Comment: Modified as per Op's need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf`:

```
printf "0x%.4x %s %s\n" $(sed -e 's/65535/N\/A/g' -e 's/[][},]//g' input  | awk '/foo/ {print $1,$NF,$(NF-1)}')
0x0000 N/A 143
0x0001 N/A 142
0x0002 N/A 141
```

**Note:** I am reusing your previous work here, only sent its output to `printf`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for handling non-decimal input data:

```
$ awk --non-decimal-data -F'[][ ,]+' '/foo/{printf "0x%04x %s %s\n", $2, ($9==65535?"N/A":$9), $8}' file
0x0000 N/A 143
0x0001 N/A 142
0x0002 N/A 141
```